# Excel Macro - Comma Separated Cells to Rows of different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets in my excel. Having following data in my excel
In first sheet, I have

---

```
 column 1: a     Column 2: p,q,r,s      Column 3: u,v,w      Column 4: x,y,z
 column 1: b     Column 2: q,r          Column 3: u,v,w      Column 4:  z
```

....... etc ##

---

with each row, representing a row and in one cell.

I would like to convert it to:

```
 1. (column 1) a   (column 2) p 
 2. (column 1) a   (column 2) q   
 3. (column 1) a   (column 2) r 
 4. (column 1) a   (column 2) s 
 5. (column 1) a                      (column 3) u 
 6. (column 1) a                      (column 3) v 
 7. (column 1) a                      (column 3) w 
 8. (column 1) a                                          (column 4) x 
 9. (column 1) a                                          (column 4) y 
 10.(column 1) a                                          (column 4) z
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow, lastcolumn, i, j, k As Long
    Dim str1, str2
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        For j = 2 To lastcolumn
            str1 = Split(Cells(i, j), ",")
            str2 = UBound(str1)
            For k = 0 To str2
                With Sheets("Sheet2")
                    .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = Cells(i, 1)
                    .Range("B" & .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = str1(k)
                End With
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Proof of Work**

[image]

Comment: @Poorni, Welcome always